Logic to replace numbers not following ordinality with averages in Excel
There is a list of numbers given to me in Excel: 0,1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8,10.
A list of such numbers should follow an increasing ordinality. So the numbers following ordinality are: 0,1,3,5,7,8,10 and numbers that do not follow are 2,4,6. Now we have to replace 2,4,6 with equidistant numbers between the 2 numbers that followed ordinality, i.e. 7 and 8. Hence, 2,4,6 become 7.25, 7.5 and 7.75. How do we implement this logic in Excel using formulas, without using VBA?
I'm unable to move past the first step itself, that is finding the ordinality. I tried : =IF(AND(A2>A1,A2>A3),"Correct","Broken"). But this gives 7,2,10 as "Broken" which is not what is required.
The expected answer is 2,4,6 are "Broken". And then they should be replaced with 7.25, 7.5 and 7.75.

Put a screenshot with input and desired output. Your expected result is confusing.

My solution is slightly different, although also with an auxiliary column.
In column A in the range A1:A10 there is data, in column B there is a check of the correct order. In B1 "Correct" is written hardcoded, from B2 down the formula:
=IF(A2>MAX(A$1:A1),"Correct","Broken")

which is analogous to yours. I assumed that the order should be ascending, as you wrote. If it were to be non-descending, the sign > should be changed to >= and the results could be different.
In column C (from C1), the formula:
=IF(B1="Correct",A1,LET(a,XLOOKUP("Correct",B$1:B1,A$1:A1,,,-1),
b,XLOOKUP("Correct",B2:B$10,A2:A$10), a+(b-a)*PERCENTRANK(ROW(a:b),ROW())))

The formula takes advantage of features of the new XLOOKUP function (lookup backwards, returning a reference, not a value).

NEW VARIANT
Now the sample data is in the range A13:A22.
In the new variant, the formula in column B needs to be changed.
In the outermost cells of column B I hardcoded "Correct". Modified formula from B14 down:
=IF(AND(A2>MAX(FILTER(A$13:A13,A$13:A13<A$22)),A14<A$22),"Correct","Broken")

The formula in column C only requires addresses to be matched (formula in C13):
=IF(B13="Correct",A13,LET(a,XLOOKUP("Correct",B$13:B13,A$13:A13,,,-1),
    b,XLOOKUP("Correct",B14:B$22,A14:A$22),a+(b-a)*PERCENTRANK(ROW(a:b),ROW())))



Thanks for the answer. How can we modify it so that if a number greater than the maximum values exists in the list instead of the last place, it is still recalculated? Ex - 0,1,3,10,5,7,2,4,6,10 or 0,1,3,15,5,7,2,4,6,10. To clarify - the maximum value is always the last place value. In these 2 examples 10 and 15 should be treated as broken and should be replaced with an equidistant number

It will be difficult to solve this in just one or two formulas because of the repeated iteration that's required. In other words, you'll need to perform multiple passes through the numbers to identify which ones are 'out of order' and how to adjust them.
One possible algorithm might look something like this:

Perform a first pass to identify the 'out of order' numbers (keeping track of the 'largest so far' at all times).
Perform a second pass to count the number of 'wrong' numbers in each batch between two 'correct' numbers.
For each 'wrong' batch, use the lower bound, upper bound and size to calculate the intermediate intervals.

This is not straightforward. To get you started, here's an illustration of how this might look when applied in Excel. (I have changed the first number in your list from 0 to 0.1, to distinguish clearly from the three zeros in the boxed cells which form part of the calculations for those columns. The two blue cells refer to B4 and C13 respectively.)

The formulas in row 4 are as follows. Each formula is copied down the full height of the table.

B4: Your original number
C4: =IF(B4>=D3, B4, D3)
D4: =IF(B4=C4, TRUE, FALSE)
E4: =IF(D4, C4, E5)
F4: =IF(D4, 0, F3+1)
G4: =IF(D4, IF(F3>0, G3+1, 0), F4)
H4: =IF(G4=0, 0, IF(H5>0, H5, G4))
I4: =IF(H4=0, 0, (E4-C3)/H4)
J4: =I4*G4
K4: =IF(J4=0, B4, C3+J4)

You could certainly compress some of this, but I have broken it down so you can see how the algorithm works. You might need to adapt this to your precise needs.
A couple of warnings about this approach:

Increasing ordinality is the only requirement. This means that if, say, the third number in your list is very large (100, say), it will nonetheless be considered to be 'in order', and all subsequent numbers 'out of order'.

The first and last numbers in your list are assumed to be ordered correctly (otherwise there will be no 'bounds' for the corresponding interval at the extremity of your list).


